# Display Json data to php file one by one

Tags: php, json

I have JSON data like this

```
{
"no":"11",
"colorname":"Silver",
"colorgroupname":"MEDIUM SILVER"
}
```

How i can display to php file like this

```
<div>
   <label>No :</label> 11
</div>
<div>
   <label>Color Name :</label> Silver
</div>
<div>
   <label>Color Group Name:</label> MEDIUM SILVER
</div>
```

Comment: Start with `json_decode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this

```
<?php
$json = '{"no":"11","colorname":"Silver","colorgroupname":"MEDIUM SILVER"}';
$arr= json_decode($json,true);
$str="";
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
$str.="<div><label>$key :</label> $val</div>";
}
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: i get error warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given how fix this.

Comment: while passing make json as string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$data=json_decode('{"no":"11","colorname":"Silver","colorgroupname":"MEDIUM SILVER"}');
?>
<div>
   <label>No :</label> <?php echo $data->no; ?>
</div>
<div>
   <label>Color Name :</label> <?php echo $data->colorname; ?>
</div>
<div>
   <label>Color Group Name:</label> <?php echo $data->colorgroupname; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $str = '{
    "no":"11",
    "colorname":"Silver",
    "colorgroupname":"MEDIUM SILVER"
    }';
    $jsObj = json_decode($str);
    ?>

<div>
   <label>No :</label> <?php echo $jsObj->no;?>
</div>
<div>
   <label>Color Name :</label> <?php echo $jsObj->colorname;?>
</div>
<div>
   <label>Color Group Name:</label> <?php echo $jsObj->colorgroupname;?>
</div>
```